# When do you need to call IDisposable, if you are using `using` statements?

Tags: c#, .net

I was reading another answer.  And it made me wonder, when do does one need to explicitly call Dispose if I am using `using` statements?

EDIT:

Just to vindicate myself from being a total know-nothing, the reason I asked was because someone on another thread said something implying there was a good reason to have to call Dispose manually...  So I figured, why not ask about it?

Comment: I love these kind of seemingly simple questions on StackOverflow. I am always surprised how much information you can get out of such a question. I didn't know about the object initializers problem...

Comment: SO is definitely an awesome website.  I love it here.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You don't. The `using` statement does it for you.

---

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx), this code example:

```
using (Font font1 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f)) 
{
    byte charset = font1.GdiCharSet;
}
```

is expanded, when compiled, to the following code (note the extra curly braces to create the limited scope for the object):

```
{
  Font font1 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f);
  try
  {
    byte charset = font1.GdiCharSet;
  }
  finally
  {
    if (font1 != null)
      ((IDisposable)font1).Dispose();
  }
}
```

---

**Note:** As [@timvw mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545062/when-do-you-need-to-call-idisposable-if-you-are-using-using-statments/545139#545139), if you chain methods or use object initializers in the using statement itself and an exception is thrown, the object won't be disposed. Which makes sense if you look at what it will be expanded to. For example:

```
using(var cat = new Cat().AsDog())
{
   // Pretend a cat is a dog
}
```

expands to

```
{
  var cat = new Cat().AsDog(); // Throws
  try
  {
    // Never reached
  }
  finally
  {
    if (cat != null)
      ((IDisposable)cat).Dispose();
  }
}
```

`AsDog` will obviously throw an exception, since a cat can never be as awesome as a dog. The cat will then never be disposed of. Of course, some people may argue that cats should never be disposed of, but that's another discussion...

Anyways, just make sure that what you do `using( here )` is safe and you are good to go. (Obviously, if the constructor fails, the object won't be created to begin with, so no need to dispose).

Comment: How awesome is it that the Advertisement as I read this is a beagle looking for a job on Careers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 12):

Normally you don't. This is the point of the using statement. There is however a situation where you have to be careful:

If you reassign the variable to another value the using statement will only call the Dispose method on the original value.

```
using (someValue = new DisposableObject())
{
    someValue = someOtherValue;
}
```

The compiler will even give you a **Warning** about this:

> Possibly incorrect assignment to local 'someValue' which is the argument to a using or lock statement. The Dispose call or unlocking will happen on the original value of the local.

Comment: I believe this warning is changed to an error in C# 3.5: "error CS1656: Cannot assign to 'someValue' because it is a 'using variable'"

Answer (score 10):

Be careful when using c# 3.0 object initializers though. An example can be found here: http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/01/15/avoid-object-initializers-amp-the-using-statement.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Never. It will call Dispose once the statements inside using blocks finish execution.

Answer (score 3):

The whole point of the using statement is that if your object implements IDisposable, the dipose will be called at the end of the code block.  That's what it's there for, to do it automaticaly for you.

Answer (score 3):

As far as i know

```
using (var myDisposable = new MyDisposable())
{
   ...
}
```

is basically translated by the compiler to

```
var myDisposable = new MyDisposable()
try
{
   ...
}
finally
{
   myDisposable.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: It also encloses the entire block in braces to limit the scope of myDisposable, and adds a check in the finally block to only execute Dispose() on non-null instances of myDisposable.