# in C#.NET, opening a connection with the using keyword, do I need to close and dispose the connection or does .NET do it for me?

Tags: .net, c#, database

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [When do you need to call IDisposable, if you are using using statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545062/when-do-you-need-to-call-idisposable-if-you-are-using-using-statements)
>   [Using statement and Close methods.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708213/using-statement-and-close-methods)

Do I need to add .Close() and .Dispose() to the end of this block?

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: This is a common question, so a quick search will answer your question faster and better than posting it again.  e.g., the following were retrieve by searching "c# using statement": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708213/using-statement-and-close-methods, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/545062/when-do-you-need-to-call-idisposable-if-you-are-using-using-statements, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567138/when-should-i-use-using-blocks-in-c

Answer (score 11):

No, `using` specifically calls `Dispose`. In the case of a `SqlConnection` , `Dispose` calls `Close` if the connection is open.

Answer (score 2):

No, you do not need to do anything.

```
using (x) { .... }
```

is rewritten as

```
try { .... } finally { if (x != null) x.Dispose(); }
```

And furthermore, `Dispose() == Close()` for a well written IDisposable class.

Answer (score 1):

[this questio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376068/does-end-using-close-an-open-sql-connection)n about VB.NET says no

Answer (score 0):

Calling *Dispose* is always redundant in a using block.

Even if Close is called by Dispose in many cases (as with the Connection), it is no bad practise to call it anyway IMO.

So if the code seems clearer to you with the Close: Write it - it won't cause any negative side-effects.